# Get list of global IDs with the material name with Python

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to generate a list of global lDs and the material that is attached.

To get the global IDs I have tried:

```
objects_with_ID = [ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.IFC Object.GlobalId[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried the following but I receive a syntax error: 'code' import bpy
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if o.type=='MESH':
        material = o.active_material
        guid = o.GlobalId 
        break 'code'

Comment: I have also tried the following that returns the 'Name' of the property but not its 'Value': import bpy
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if o.type=='MESH':
        material = o.active_material.name
        Guid = o.BIMObjectProperties.attributes[1].name
print(material)
print(Guid)

Comment: please copy and paste your error in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working:

```
import bpy
import csv
import os

outputFile = 'C:/Temp/0_IFCGuid_IFCMaterial.csv'
f = open(outputFile,'w')

for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if o.type=='MESH':
        material = o.active_material.name
        global_id_index = o.BIMObjectProperties.attributes.find('GlobalId')
        guid = o.BIMObjectProperties.attributes[global_id_index].string_value
        print(guid)
        print(material)
        f.writelines(guid)
        f.writelines('\n')
        f.writelines(material)
        f.writelines('\n')
f.close()
```